# 9 digit zip codes are reporting LEN of 12

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, openrowset

I am attempting to resolve some difficulties in getting zip codes to display properly.

The original spreadsheet has zip codes of mixed 5 and 9 digit formats. After the import process, these 9 digit zip codes are reporting a length of 12 digits. Now when I try to add a hyphen '-' to the 9 digit zip codes I'm getting abnormal results and errors because of the wrong length and various data type conversion issues.

The import was performed using an openrowset method for importing the data from a spreadsheet.

When I query the newly imported data, I see the zip codes showing the same as they were in the spreadsheet, but the length is wrong.

```
SELECT ZIP,
    LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(Zip))) AS ZIPLENGTH
  FROM XLS_IMPORT
```

```
ZIP         ZIPLENGTH
45750       5
432013256   12
441153221   12
44120       5
441351362   12
```

If I select the left 9 characters of the data, everything gets converted to float and the zip codes are now unreadable.

```
SELECT LEFT(ZIP,9) FROM XLS_IMPORT
WHERE LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(ZIP))) = 12
```

```
ZIP
4.32013e+
4.42034e+
4.56637e+
4.41153e+
4.36045e+
4.41133e+
```

How can I get these zip codes back to the correct 9 digits? Or how can I add a hyphen to those 9 digit zip codes which are reporting length of 12? My end goal is to simply get the 9 digit zip code to have a hyphen in the middle.

The datatype of the `Zip` column is `float`.

I just discovered that some of my spreadsheets like NJ and NY have an apostrophe before the leading 0 in the zip code. I will need to investigate how to handle the '0xxxx zip codes to get this to work on some of my spreadsheet imports.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Zip codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_code) are strings, not numbers. Some of them have 1 or even 2 (but not more than 2) [leading zeroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ZIP_code_prefixes#Starts_with_0). The datatype in the import table should be `VARCHAR(10)` so that it can hold 5 digit and 9 digit + hyphen zip codes. Even if you never have to store [postal codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_code) of other countries, and even if the values will only ever have numeric digits (i.e. 0 - 9), this data is still string data, just like phone numbers.

Based on the import query shown in your other question ([automate import and export of process EXCEL -> SQL SERVER - > EXCEL without using SSIS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138482/automate-import-and-export-of-process-excel-sql-server-excel-without-usin) ):

```
SELECT * INTO XLS_IMPORT
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\RSG_ETL_Tool\Ohio\OH.xls; HDR=YES; IMEX=1',
'SELECT * FROM [OH$]');
```

I would suggest *not* relying upon the `SELECT INTO` construct to create the `XLS_IMPORT` table, but instead create the import table(s) manually, and then use the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM OPENROWSET()` construct. Doing this would allow you to do the following things to improve this situation:

1. Create the `ZipCode` field as `VARCHAR(10)`
2. Convert the values on the way in using the [STR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx) function which, for an initial `FLOAT` value of `432013256`, will return  `432013256` instead of `4.32013e+008` (which is what you get when you convert to `VARCHAR`).
3. Fix any missing leading zeroes using something like the following:

   ```
   CASE
      WHEN LEN(LTRIM(STR(@ZipColumn))) BETWEEN 3 AND 4
             THEN RIGHT('0000' + LTRIM(STR(@ZipColumn)), 5)
      WHEN LEN(LTRIM(STR(@ZipColumn))) BETWEEN 7 AND 8
             THEN RIGHT('0000' + LTRIM(STR(@ZipColumn)), 9)
      WHEN LEN(LTRIM(STR(@ZipColumn))) IN (5, 9) THEN LTRIM(STR(@ZipColumn))
      ELSE 'BadZipCode'
   END
   ```

Example:

```
DECLARE @ZipColumn FLOAT = 032013256.000000;

SELECT CASE
          WHEN LEN(LTRIM(STR(@ZipColumn))) BETWEEN 3 AND 4
                 THEN RIGHT('0000' + LTRIM(STR(@ZipColumn)), 5)
          WHEN LEN(LTRIM(STR(@ZipColumn))) BETWEEN 7 AND 8
                 THEN RIGHT('0000' + LTRIM(STR(@ZipColumn)), 9)
          WHEN LEN(LTRIM(STR(@ZipColumn))) IN (5, 9) THEN LTRIM(STR(@ZipColumn))
          ELSE 'BadZipCode'
       END;
```

Returns:

```
032013256
```

Ideally, you would fix the column definition in the spreadsheet to be a string. But even if you do that, it might still be a good idea to keep this code around.

> My end goal is to simply get the 9 digit zip code to have a hyphen in the middle.

With that goal in mind, the following inline TVF can be used to both convert the `FLOAT` value to `VARCHAR`, and to add in the hyphen for ZIP + 4 values.

Code for iTVF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FormatZIPCode(@NumericZIPCode FLOAT)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS RETURN

WITH string AS
(
    SELECT  LTRIM(STR(@NumericZIPCode)) AS [Value],
            LEN(LTRIM(STR(@NumericZIPCode))) AS [Size]
), converted AS
(
SELECT  CASE
                WHEN st.[Value] IS NULL THEN NULL
                WHEN st.[Size] BETWEEN 3 AND 4
                    THEN RIGHT('0000' + st.[Value], 5)
                WHEN st.[Size] BETWEEN 7 AND 8
                    THEN RIGHT('0000' + st.[Value], 9)
                WHEN st.[Size] IN (5, 9)
                    THEN st.[Value]
                ELSE 'BadZipCode'
            END AS [ZIP],
            st.[Size] AS [OriginalSize]
    FROM        string st
)
SELECT  IIF(cnv.[OriginalSize] >= 7, STUFF(cnv.[ZIP], 6, 0, '-'), cnv.[ZIP])
               AS [FormattedZIPCode]
FROM        converted cnv;
```

Test:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (VALUES (CONVERT(FLOAT, NULL)), (1), (12), (123), (1234), (12345),
                (123456), (1234567), (12345678), (123456789)) src(val)
CROSS APPLY dbo.FormatZIPCode(src.[val]) frmt;
```

Returns:

```
val         FormattedZIPCode
---------   ----------------
NULL        NULL
1           BadZipCode
12          BadZipCode
123         00123
1234        01234
12345       12345
123456      BadZipCode
1234567     00123-4567
12345678    01234-5678
123456789   12345-6789
```

In order to be clearer about what is being suggested, the following shows all of the suggestions noted above put together:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.XLS_IMPORT
(
  Col1     DataTypeForCol1,
  Col2     DataTypeForCol2,
  ZIPCode  VARCHAR(10),
  ...
);

INSERT INTO dbo.XLS_IMPORT (Col1, Col2, ZIPCode, ...)
  SELECT xls.Col1, xls.Col2, zip.[FormattedZIPCode], ...
  FROM   OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
         'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\RSG_ETL_Tool\Ohio\OH.xls; HDR=YES; IMEX=1',
         'SELECT * FROM [OH$]')
  CROSS APPLY dbo.FormatZIPCode(xls.[ZIP]) zip;
```

Some of the spreadsheets are "aware" of there being leading zeroes, and so prefixed the field in Excel with a single apostrophe so that Excel would treat the value as a string instead of as numeric (e.g. `'01234`). In that case, you can use the `REPLACE` function to strip out that apostrophe.

```
-- Test incoming string data (potentially prefixed with a single apostrophe)
SELECT  src.[val], frmt.[FormattedZIPCode],CHARINDEX(N'''', src.[val])
FROM    (VALUES (NULL), (N'''01234'), (N'''123456789'), (N'123'), (N'12345678')) src(val)
CROSS APPLY dbo.FormatZIPCode(REPLACE(src.[val], N'''', N'')) frmt;
```

However, you can't use `REPLACE` on all spreadsheets because the spreadsheets that have the `ZIP` column as numeric will do a `CONVERT_IMPLICIT` as it passes the value to the `REPLACE` function and the converted value will be in scientific notation (e.g. `1.23457e+008`). So if you can't be certain which datatype is going to be returned by `OPENROWSET`, then you can use `IIF` (or `CASE` if using a version of SQL Server prior to 2012) and `CHARINDEX` to test for the presence of an apostrophe. If the data is being returned as `FLOAT`, then the implicit conversion to `VARCHAR` that will occur when passing the values into `CHARINDEX` will not be an issue since there is no apostrophe in `1.23457e+008` and the converted value is only going to `CHARINDEX` and not to `dbo.FormatZIPCode`.

```
-- Test handling incoming data as both numeric and string
SELECT  src.[val], frmt.[FormattedZIPCode],CHARINDEX(N'''', src.[val])
FROM    (VALUES (CONVERT(FLOAT, NULL)), (1), (12), (123), (1234), (12345),
                (123456), (1234567), (12345678), (123456789)) src(val)
CROSS APPLY dbo.FormatZIPCode(
       IIF(CHARINDEX(N'''', src.[val]) > 0, REPLACE(src.[val], N'''', N''), src.[val])
                             ) frmt;

SELECT  src.[val], frmt.[FormattedZIPCode]
FROM    (VALUES (N'''01234'), (N'''123456789'), (N'123'), (N'12345678')) src(val)
CROSS APPLY dbo.FormatZIPCode(
       IIF(CHARINDEX(N'''', src.[val]) > 0, REPLACE(src.[val], N'''', N''), src.[val])
                             ) frmt;
```

Answer (score 8):

Obviously at this point you've realized that zip codes should be stored as strings not numbers.  If for no other reason than the fact that foreign (non-US) zip codes frequently have letters in them.

That said let's go back to your original question.  Why was your length showing 5 when you had 5 digits and 12 when you were only storing 9 digits. That has to do with the way the [LEN function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) works.  If you look at the XML execution plan for this sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (MyFloat float, MyStr varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (12345,'12345'),(123456789,'123456789')
SELECT len(MyFloat), len(MyStr) FROM #temp
```

You'll notice these two lines:

```
<ScalarOperator ScalarString="len(CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(23),[tempdb].[dbo].[#temp].[MyFloat],0))">
<ScalarOperator ScalarString="len([tempdb].[dbo].[#temp].[MyStr])">
```

Do you see how behind the scenes there is a `CONVERT_IMPLICIT` to convert the float value into a `varchar(23)` before getting the `LEN`. (From what I can tell `LEN` actually only works on strings.)

So let's take a look at what that `CONVERT_IMPLICIT` is actually returning by doing an explicit conversion.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(23), MyFloat) FROM #temp
```

[image]

And now we see that `12345` converts cleanly.  `123456789` required scientific notation however.  Giving us `1.23457e+008`.  Which is 12 characters long.

Answer (score 1):

The zip code was imported as a float data type. I was unable to convert the column directly from float to varchar(10). Instead I converted the data type from float to decimal, and then from decimal to varchar(10). Now the column is reporting the correct number of zip code digits (9). This now allows for inserting a hyphen into the 9 digit zip codes.